# Site logo design?

Tags: discussion, top-7, design

Assuming the site exits beta in a few months, what kind of logo should it have?.

Comment: Please suggest your stack of d6s so I can vote it up :)

Comment: +1 for the stack of d6. As Richard said, you should post it as an answer

Comment: Is this question just for the logo, or does it include general look & feel of the site too. Just thought I'd ask, as I quite like the hand-drawn look it curretly has, links into RPGs for me.

Comment: It looked like this was just for the logo, so I created a question about general look and feel, and put my idea there http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/162/look-and-feel-of-final-site-design/163#163.

Comment: I was just curious about logo options.

Comment: -1 for d6s.  d20s say "RPG" so much better.

Comment: There will be more to the design than just the logo.  Shouldn't the logo exist in the context of a wider site design?

Comment: @Jon: Indeed it should.

Answer (score 18):

If we've got room, I'm all for a toppling tower made from a full set of polyhedral die:  d20, d12, d10, d8, d6, d4.

Comment: +1 - See [my comment below](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/108/site-logo-design#comment-1719).

Answer (score 11):

How about just a d20?

Comment: Feels d20-system specific; a d6 is more ubiquitous and system-independent.

Comment: A [d20](http://or.sstatic.net/chat/Img/rpg-d20.png) is generic, yet tends to exclude mundane games like craps and Trival Persuits.  Everyone in RPG, regardless of system, at least recognizes a d20.

Comment: Agreed with Ron.  The d6 is too ubiquitous, stretching far and wide outside the realm of RPGs.  The d20 on the other hand, is very recognizably an icon of tabletop RPGs.

Comment: @Ron @TML @Iszi - Why not a `d8` or a `d10` or a `d12` or any of the other non-`d6` dice which aren't the flagship symbol for [systems our site is being too strongly associated with in the eyes of new users](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/774/how-do-we-get-more-questions-about-things-besides-dd-4e)?

Comment: The d20 feels more "iconic" to me, but I have no objection to any of the other polyhedrals except for the d6 - the d6 is far too generic to me. How about starting new "answers" for each of the various polyhedrals and we see which one wins the most votes?

Answer (score 10):

(I like that stack of d6's.)

If it doesn't turn out to be that one, a die with a questionmark on the top face might be good.

Comment: I like the single d6 with a question mark - I think the stack of d6's might be a bit difficult to render recognisably as a logo.

Comment: +1 - I've [already expressed an apprexiation for the question mark on a dice idea](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/477/can-we-get-a-graphic-design/493#493).

Comment: -1 for the d6s, +1 for the question mark.  Net vote: 0

Answer (score 6):

A stack of d6s toppling over similar to the stackoverflow logo.

(Answer added at request of commenters)

Comment: +1 it makes sense. fits very well.

Comment: -1 if I could.  You just can't fit a stack of d6 in a 16x16 icon.  Even if you are using the larger icons, you need at least 9x9 pixels to represent a die face, more when you start rotating it.

Comment: -1 d6s don't really scream "RPG" so much as d20s

Answer (score 5):

I think a dice-tower of assorted dice toppling could be more fun. But we don't have that many pixels to choose from.

Answer (score 3):

I think about Papers, pencil and dices.

Answer (score 1):

Not logo design, but: if the current look and feel with the graph paper just had a bunch of rooms on it... might be too D&D/fantasy specific, though.

Comment: It's iconic and flexible.  RQ and Call of Cthulhu have their fair share of connected-room scenarios, too, and they are used in wargaming.  It's maybe got less in the way of a special D&D association than exotic polyhedral die.

Answer (score 1):

Alternately, I could go for a hexahedron, tetrahedron and icosahedron (d6, d4 and d20) arranged like the boxes in [gamedev.stackexchange.com](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/)'s logo.

Answer (score -2):

I'm going to say a d6 being touched by a glowing wand.  Yeah, the wand is fantasy-centric, but probably we can admit that so is the hobby.

Honestly, I would really rather the stack of different types of polyhedral dice, but this logo has to scale down to a 16x16 favicon.  We have *very* little real estate to work with when you take that into consideration.

Comment: -1 - I disagree; while the hobby is [fantasy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fantasy_%28psychology%29)-centric it's not [fantasy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fantasy)-centric. I for one prefer any other setting (Steam Punk; Superheroes; Space Opera...) over the fantasy setting.