# Who decides what design we get when we graduate?

Tags: discussion, design, stack-exchange

I know the answer to this probably is the S.E. staff, but what if the community is not happy with the design they apply? Can we petition a change?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd rather concentrate on graduating rather than worry about this.

That said, I know that during previous graduations the site design was vetted with the community and feedback was taken into account.  There is no reason to suspect we would be different here.

SE has the final say, but there is no reason for them to force a hated design upon the community.

Comment: Apparently the number of questions is the only thing keeping us from graduating. Perhaps I should open another discussion as to why we don't have enough questions/what we can do to have more?

Comment: I don't think Q on meta count...

Comment: @Pureferret does this Q not belong here? It didn't feel right, asking in it Main.

Comment: @OddCore, I mean that I don't think out questions per day count is affected by questions on meta

Comment: oh, I know that. The question I would post on meta would be about how we can get more questions/why we dont have enough _in main_

Comment: @OddCore - Traffic in general needs to increase.  Pumping out questions just for the sake of questions won't lead to quality.

Comment: @PatLudwig Oh, for sure. I wasn't suggesting we spam questions. But we could make the extra effort and find out questions to boost traffic.

Answer (score 0):

We provide input here on Meta, SE (more specifically SE's designer) does the final.  See the previous questions on this topic - [design](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/design). The designer (Jin at the time, it's been a while) [chipped in some](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/739/design-ideas-for-rpg-site).

I do hear rumblings that we may get a design without graduating, but it was part of a pretty hedgey email about beta maybe isn't beta etc etc...  Don't let that stop you from trying to boost site traffic.